# Trying to create a cube with 6 sides and set the colors for each side in Java

Tags: java

Three classes. Cube, Side, and Game. I am trying to create a cube and set the colors for each side. I am using an array in my side class Side[] block = new Side[6]; I have two methods in my Side class, one constructor for the color and method to return it:

```
public String color;

public Side(String color){
this.color = color;
}

public String getColor(){
return color;
}
```

In my Cube class, I am having trouble with this constructor:

```
public Cube(String top, String back, String bottom, String front, String left, String         right){

this.block[0].color = top;
this.block[1].color = back;
this.block[2].color = bottom;
this.block[3].color = front;
this.block[4].color = left;
this.block[5].color = right;    
}
```

In my Game (Main) class, I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Cube c1 = new Cube("Red", "White", "Blue", "Red", "Green", "White");
}
```

When I try to create a cube in my Game (Main) class, it gives a null pointer exception for the line of code in the Game class and for the first line of code in the Cube constructor in the Cube class. Can someone please tell me what is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: `block[0]` is null.  You must first initialize your array before you can set its values.

Comment: Please show the complete Cube class

Comment: try `this.block[0] = new Side()` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Sides are not instantiated yet, i.e. `this.block[0]` is actually null.

You could try:

```
this.block[0] = new Side(top);
this.block[1] = new Side(back);
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize your `block` array as follows:

```java
Side[] block = new Side[] {new Side(), new Side(), new Side(), new Side(), new Side(), new Side()};
```